# TMG forcing intranet connections through port 443 instead of firewall

Tags: powershell, proxy

Something bizarre happened to production server that I am losing sleep over. We use Forefront TMG to handle our connections with external vendors. We use a firewall to handle requests within our network. For some reason when I am trying to access an API using an https request within our network it is trying to access it via the TMG proxy. The odd thing is, it's not supposed to, nor has it ever done this until all of a sudden. It's as if the hostname and port requested are cached into using the proxy. I've since gone in and cleaned out the cache for the TMG client, but it still does the same thing. The proxy server is setup the correct way and there is no traffic even hitting the firewall. I have verified this.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

On a side note, the day it started crashing I was playing around with setting a PowerShell script to access the proxy to reach an external website. I don't think  any of the options I used below could have made any permanent changes and from what I can tell only set variables and objects that were specific to the scripts session. Here's the 3 options I played around with:

```
# 1
$url = "https://someurl.com"
$WebProxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy("http://svr1.madeuptmgproxyname.com:8080", $true)
$WebClient = New-Object Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Proxy = $webproxy
$WebClient.proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$WebClient.DownloadString($url) 

# 2 
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add('Invoke-WebRequest:Proxy','http://svr1.madeuptmgproxyname.com:8080') 
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add('Invoke-WebRequest:ProxyUseDefaultCredentials',$true)

# 3 
$url = "https://someurl.com"
$ProxyUri = [Uri]$null
$Proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
$Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
$ProxyUri = $Proxy.GetProxy("$url")
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PowerShell? PowerShell has no control over this. TMG either allows the traffic or not. TMG has not been supported or even sold for years now. So a real blast from the past. Talking to an endpoint either allows the connection and responds or not. Traffic patterns are controlled by your network, browser config or PAC files direction you to your outbound gateway. Check your TMG ingress/egress rules directly.

Comment: That's why I said I didn't think those PowerShell commands couldn't have affected it. The reason I posted those is you can literally route traffic through the browser in the background, and I didn't want to have any permanent changes done. I'm posting what I can out of slight ignorance and full desperation. The reason a lot of us come here to post questions. I've had the proxy team take a look at this with no luck, then the firewall team with zero results. I am here out of desperation.

Comment: I realize TMG is ancient, but it's not my choice for running it. What I know is the proxy isn't authenticating because the credentials aren't being passed through, so it defaults to anonymous and gets blocked. Everything is routed through the TMG client itself, so browser settings shouldn't have affected anything. I did open the browser and force TLS 1.2 on a website that required it for testing, but everything crashed later that afternoon. After running some Invoke-WebRequests I forced the code to choose between TLS 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 and then magically the request was successful.

Comment: This leads me to believe it's a TLS issue. I am getting with the person who manages this server to verify everything is set in vSphere to support the entire range because everything in the registry certainly reflects that. Also, I understand running TLS 1.0 and 1.1 isn't safe, but there are things that will break until things out of my control can be addressed. Thankfully it's only an L4/3.5 problem.

Comment: Glad to here you tested the security session block. TLS level have been raising its head in many places I've come across, but not PowerShell specific. Some solutions that are Exchange -based have gotten smacked down by not having the correct TLS settings. Now, considering that the TLS settings warning is nowadays common knowledge, I would not have assumed your org would not have already addressed that. Mea culpa,  Yet, TMG was a dead thing long before these TLS constraints became a thing. Legacy stuff always the catch22. Note: it's the destination that mandates channel stuff, not source.